# Hammerspoon Window management does not work as expected on secondary monitor

Tags: lua, hammerspoon

I'm new to Lua and hammerspoon and can not for the life of me figure out why the below code works fine on my primary screen, but the cycling though positions does not work on my secondary monitor. hitting the shortcut on windows on the secondary monitor enables the first position, but a second press does nothing.

Reading the docs, hs.screen.mainScreen() enable the current focused screen so it should work?

As an aside...the secondary monitor is actually physically the same monitor as the primary running PBP (otherwise graphics card can not handle the resolution)

I've only posted the code i think is relevant below:

```
local rightScreen = hs.screen.primaryScreen(0x600003f98880)
local leftScreen = rightScreen:toWest()

function bindKey(key, fn)
  hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "ctrl","alt"}, key, fn)
end

grid = {
  {key="q", units={positions.leftthird, positions.left50, positions.left66}},
  {key="w", units={positions.middlethird}},
  {key="e", units={positions.rightthird}},
  {key="r", units={positions.left50, positions.lower50Left50, positions.upper50Left50, positions.upper50, positions.lower50}}, -- virker IKKE på sekundære skærm
  {key="t", units={positions.right50, positions.lower50Right50, positions.upper50Right50, positions.upper50, positions.lower50}}, -- virker IKKE på sekundære skærm

}

hs.fnutils.each(grid, function(entry)
  bindKey(entry.key, function()
    local units = entry.units
    local screen = hs.screen.mainScreen()
    local window = hs.window.focusedWindow()
    local windowGeo = window:frame()

    local index = 0
    hs.fnutils.find(units, function(unit)
      index = index + 1

      local geo = hs.geometry.new(unit):fromUnitRect(screen:frame()):floor()
     return windowGeo:equals(geo)
    end)
    if index == #units then index = 0 end

    window:moveToUnit(units[index + 1])
  end)
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can do is post my own code for a similar purpose that I wrote 3+ years ago and it's been working perfectly since then, on both internal and external monitors.  As you can see I'm using `win:setFrame` instead of `:moveToUnit`. Sorry I can't help in debugging your problem but I've forgotten Lua and Hammerspoon already... Hope that helps

```
function coords ()
  return hs.window.focusedWindow(), hs.window.focusedWindow():frame(),
         hs.window.focusedWindow():screen(), hs.window.focusedWindow():screen():frame()
end


hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "left", function()

  local win, wf, scr, sf = coords()

  if wf.x <= sf.x and wf.w <= math.floor(sf.w/3) then
    wf.x = sf.x
    wf.w = math.floor(sf.w/4)
  elseif wf.x <= sf.x and wf.w <= math.floor(sf.w/2) then
    wf.x = sf.x
    wf.w = math.floor(sf.w/3)
  else
    wf.x = sf.x
    wf.w = math.floor(sf.w/2)
  end
  wf.y=sf.y
  wf.h=sf.h
  win:setFrame(wf, 0)
end)


hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "right", function()

  local win, wf, scr, sf = coords()

  if wf.x >= math.floor(sf.x + sf.w/3) and wf.w <= math.floor(sf.w/3) then
    wf.w = sf.w/4
    wf.x = math.floor(sf.x + 3 * sf.w/4)
  elseif wf.x >= math.floor(sf.x + sf.w/2) and wf.w <= math.floor(sf.w/2) then
    wf.w = sf.w/3
    wf.x = math.floor(sf.x + 2 * sf.w/3)
  else
    wf.w = sf.w/2
    wf.x = math.floor(sf.x + sf.w/2)
  end
  wf.y=sf.y
  wf.h=sf.h
  win:setFrame(wf, 0)
end)


hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "up", function()

  local win, wf, scr, sf = coords()

  win:setFrame(sf, 0)
end)

hs.hotkey.bind({"cmd", "alt", "ctrl"}, "down", function()

  local win, wf, scr, sf = coords()

  if wf.x ~= math.floor(sf.x + sf.w/3) and wf.w ~= math.floor(sf.w/3) then
    wf.w = math.floor(sf.w/3)
    wf.x = math.floor(sf.x + sf.w/3)
  else
    wf.w = sf.w/2
    wf.x = math.floor(sf.x + sf.w/4)
  end
  wf.y=sf.y
  wf.h=sf.h

  win:setFrame(wf, 0)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a modification of the ArrangeDesktop spoon which can help with saving and arranging window positions.  It might help you